# How to filter ObjectId that will not match anything in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

im struggling with filtering a query in mongodb. i need the data to not match any objectId that might existed. i tried the methods below for string data, and works, except for objectId (thie ksiGroup path is ObjectId in type)

the filter

```
filters = {
  date: args.filters.status ? dateFilter : { $ne: '' },
  type: args.filters.type ? args.filters.type : { $ne: '' },
  ksiGroup: args.filters.ksiGroup ? args.filters.ksiGroup : { $ne: '' },
};
```

the model

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  attendees: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      default: [],
    },
  ],
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: String, required: true },
  startTime: { type: String, required: true },
  endTime: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String },
  status: { type: String },
  place: { type: String, required: true },
  point: { type: Number, required: true },
  ksiGroup: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'KSI' },
},{ timestamps: true });
```

the code is check if i set a filter for certain path or not. if no filter exist, it simply return `{ $ne: '' }` that will return anything that wasn't empty. How can i achieve this for `ksiGroup` which is an ObjectId in type?

Comment: You may do something like this with your `filter` object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919152/11711316

Comment: wow better approach, thanks for pointing that @CuongLeNgoc