# Mongoose/Express multiple conditional search criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created this webshop where I would like to be able to query mongoDB with Mongoose and express based on search word, category and location. It's working as expected, but only when I have "search, location & page" passed as parameter to my backend.

I'm looking for best practice on how to do with example.find({title:title, location:location, category:category}) in a case where sometimes location or category may not exist.

Example: user did not want to search for a word, only for a location. this would mean that title and category is blank in my query example.find({page:1, title:undefined, loation:"Stockholm", category: undefined}). I still want this to query all titles, all categories but for page 1 and location Stockholm.

Any suggestions suggestions on how to do this in an elegant way?

Best regards,
Oscar

Comment: You can try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919152/11711316

Comment: Thank you! This looks promising. Eager to test it this afternoon!

Comment: Confirming after testing it out that this approach was a success! Thanks for the assistance @CuongLeNgoc